# On the exponentiation of a stochastic matrix where the exponent is a function of matrix size

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, matrix-theory

In  [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/437354), I asked about any arbitrary **stochastic matrix** $A(n)$ of the particular form

$$A(n) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ x_{21} & x_{22} & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{n1}& \dots &\cdots&x_{nn} \end{pmatrix},$$

where  $x_{11} = 1$ and $x_{jj} < 1$ for all $j > 1$. We assume

$$\mathbf{x}(n) = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n),\\ (1,1,\cdots,1) \times A(n)^{\phi} \times  (x(n))^T = 1, \forall \phi \geq 0,\\ \mbox{one} (n) = (1,0,0,\cdots,0)_{1 \times n}$$ and $n$ is a finite constant.

My question was whether $$\lim_{\rho \to \infty} \mathbf{x}(n) \times A(n)^{\rho} \times \mbox{one} (n)^T = 1?$$ The answer is **yes**.  The next obvious question is, since $A(n)$ is a function of $n$, considering $\rho(n)$ also as an non-decreasing function of $n$, can we also conclude

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{x}(n) \times A(n)^{\rho(n)} \times one(n)^T = 1, \qquad \forall \rho(n)\;\text{s.t.}\;\frac{1}{\rho(n)} = o(1)?$$

Comment: Is $A^\rho$ in the first limit meant to be $A(n)^\rho$?  In the second limit, $n$ is not changing but $\rho$ is, so what does $\rho(n)$ mean?  Should it be $n \to \infty$?  What does "for each choice of $\forall\rho(n)$" mean—just an accidental double quantification?

Comment: @LSpice in 1st limit $\rho$ is independent of $n$, while as you correctly pointed out $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @FabianWirth dimension of the right is also $n \times n$. Matrix $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A(n) = B(n) \implies \displaystyle \forall\;  i,j \in \{1,2,\cdots, n\}\; \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{ij} = b_{ij}$.

Comment: @FabianWirth check the edits.

Comment: @FabianWirth Okk, Let's put it this way: With increasing $n$,  $A(n)^{\rho(n)}$ tends to an infinite matrix whose all elements in the first row are $1$ and the rest are $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142278/discussion-between-subhankar-ghosal-and-fabian-wirth).

Comment: Having trouble making sense of this question. You have this term, $x(n)\times one(n)^t$, but nothing is done with it; it isn't defined equal to anything. Then, you ask whether an arbitrary (row-)stochastic matrix $A(n)$ has a very specific form, but of course an arbitrary stochastic matrix need not have first row $(1\ 0\ \dots\ 0)$. You must be leaving something, maybe several things, out.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited x(n)×one(n)t part as it was a typo. My question is centered around an arbitrary stochastic matrix with a specific form, which I further clarified. 
 ,

Comment: So, there's no restriction on the entries of $x(n)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $\sum^n_{i=1} x_i = 1$

Comment: Does it say that somewhere in the problem statement, Subhankar?